# Does "Edit with Emacs" saves a local file of current edit buffer?

Tags: editing, web-browser

I'm using [Edit with Emacs](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Edit_with_Emacs) to edit Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites.
Currently I'm doing it with this message ;-)

When I click on the button under the text area of Chrome browser, I get a new file opened on Emacs.
Current file is named `emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`.
When I press save the file: `C-x C-s`, the text gets updated in the browser.

Is the file saved somewhere in the filesystem, so I can recover it locally, just in case I kill the current buffer?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may want to check out the excellent `sx.el` (https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el/) which provides a StackExchange client in Emacs.

Comment: Wow, this sx.el is great! I'm writing this comment from it... ;-) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mmm, is it possible in sx.el to refresh on the browser (visit) while I'm answering or asking?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the code it does not seem  that edit server save the contents to a file. However it does provide a hook `edit-server-done-hook` which running every time you do `edit-server-save` (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>) or `edit-server-done` (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>) you might add a function to the hook to save the current contents to a file.

A not-so-well-tested example is given below

```el
(defvar my-edit-with-emacs-backups-dir (locate-user-emacs-file "edit-with-emacs-saves"))

(unless (file-exists-p my-edit-with-emacs-backups-dir)
  (make-directory my-edit-with-emacs-backups-dir))

(defun my-backup-edit-with-emacs-contents ()
  (let ((backup-directory-alist (list (cons "." my-edit-with-emacs-backups-dir))))
    (save-excursion
      (write-region nil nil (car (find-backup-file-name (buffer-name))) nil 0))))

(add-hook 'edit-server-done-hook #'my-backup-edit-with-emacs-contents)
```

With the above the you `edit-with-buffer` contents will be backed up in `~/.emacs.d/edit-with-emacs-saves` directory whenever you do `edit-server-save` (<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd>) or `edit-server-done` (<kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>)