# Set "Edit with Emacs" major mode to markdown-mode

Tags: major-mode

I'm using [Edit with Emacs](http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Edit_with_Emacs) to edit Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange sites.
Currently I'm doing it with this message ;-)

When I click on the button under the text area of Chrome browser, I get a new file opened on Emacs.
Current file is named `emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`, which is opened in *Text mode*.
I change it to *Markdown mode*, that makes it more appropriate.

When I press save the file: `C-x C-s`, the text gets updated in the browser.
Check [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16535/does-edit-with-emacs-saves-a-local-file-of-current-edit-buffer) regarding if file is saved locally or not.
But the mode is changed back to *Text mode*.

Is there a way to open the buffer in *Markdown mode*?
Is it possible to avoid the change in the mode, when saving the buffer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browsing through the [source code of `edit-server`](https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome/blob/master/servers/edit-server.el#L52) reveals that you can either customize `edit-server-url-major-mode-alist` or set the mode in `edit-server-start-hook`.  Here's the example from the code:

```
;; Buffers are edited in `text-mode' by default; to use a different
;; major mode, change `edit-server-default-major-mode' or customize
;; `edit-server-url-major-mode-alist' to specify major modes based
;; on the remote URL:
;;
;; (setq edit-server-url-major-mode-alist
;;       '(("github\\.com" . markdown-mode)))
;;
;; Alternatively, set the mode in `edit-server-start-hook'. For
;; example:
;;
;; (add-hook 'edit-server-start-hook
;;           (lambda ()
;;             (when (string-match "github.com" (buffer-name))
;;               (markdown-mode))))
```